# Setting comboBox filters for multiple tabs in desktop application with excel as source

Tags: python, excel, pyqt5

I am having issues with my desktop app, Python based. Using PyQt5 I have created comboBoxes for my tabs (which are in fact the 4 sheets of my Excel source). When I select an option from the dropdown filters the rows are not filtered. The thing is that it is working fine in the last tab (tab4) but not in the others.  I have defined the filter columns for each tab in tab_configurations in my **init** method (as they are different):

```
def filterData(self, tab_name, column):
        try:
            #fetch the current tab widget
            tab = getattr(self, tab_name)
            self.clear_search_bar_for_tab(tab)

            table = self.tab_table_mapping.get(tab)
            comboBox = self.comboBoxes[(tab_name, column)]
            filterText = comboBox.currentText().lower() if comboBox.currentIndex() > 0 else ""

            if not table:
                print("Table not found for current tab")
                return

            # filter from dropdown
            for row in range(table.rowCount()):
                item = table.item(row, column)
                itemText = item.text().lower() if item else ""
                should_hide = bool(filterText) and filterText not in itemText
                table.setRowHidden(row, should_hide)

                print(f"Filtering {filterText}, item {itemText}, hide : {should_hide}")

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred in filterData: {e}")

    def addFilters(self, tab, table, df, layout):
        tab_name = str(tab.objectName())
        tab_config = self.tab_configurations.get(tab_name, {})
        filter_columns = tab_config.get('filter_columns', {})

        filters_h_layout = QHBoxLayout()

        filters_container = QWidget()
       
        self.comboBoxes = {}

        default_combo_box_size = QSize(150, 22)

        bold_font = QFont()
        bold_font.setBold(True)

        for column, label_text in filter_columns.items():
            filter_v_layout = QHBoxLayout()

            label = QLabel(label_text)
            label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter | Qt.AlignBottom)
            label.setFont(bold_font)
            filter_v_layout.addWidget(label)

            comboBox = QComboBox()
            comboBox.setStyleSheet("""
                QComboBox {
                    border: 1px solid #0078D7;
                    border-radius: 1px;
                    padding: 1px;
                    background-color: #FFFFFF;
                    color: #333;
                    margin: 1px;
                }
                QComboBox::drop-down {
                    subcontrol-origin: padding;
                    subcontrol-position: center right'
                    width: 20px;
                    border-left-width: 1px;
                    border-left-color: #0078D7;
                    border-left-style: solid;
                    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
                    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
                }

            """)
            comboBox.setFixedSize(default_combo_box_size)
            uniqueValues = [str(value) for value in df.iloc[:, column].unique()]
            uniqueValues.insert(0, "")  # add an empty value for no filter
            comboBox.addItems(uniqueValues)
            self.comboBoxes[(tab_name, column)] = comboBox
            print(f"Adding filter for {tab_name}, columns {column}")
            comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(
                lambda index, tab_name=tab_name, column=column: self.filterData(tab_name, column))

            filter_v_layout.addWidget(comboBox)

            filters_h_layout.addLayout(filter_v_layout)
            filters_h_layout.setSpacing(5)

        filters_h_layout.addStretch()

        layout.addLayout(filters_h_layout)
        layout.setSpacing(20)
```

I have created also a search_bar , but I have added condition to be able to use the filter only if the search bar is clear.
I have prints that show that filters for each tab are added correctly, as defined in the filter_columns from my tab_configurations.
I want to be able to use filters defined as per each tab. Selecting 1 option should hide the others.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].